# jar files are deleted on restart

Tags: java, jar

The application we are currently developing has a bizarre issue. Occassionally, all the jar files (except one) are deleted from the lib folder. Has any one seen this at all. I've seen references on Google to temp jar files but not real/live/active ones.

Comment: Does your AntiVirus Software says anything?

Comment: what application is this? A Java EE application or a standalone one? And what is this lib directory that you are referring to?

Comment: Hi .. no nothing in anti-virus logs and its a standalone application. The lib directory sits under the applications install root. The application is a Java core application with an Adobe Air front end (using the Merapi bridge).

Comment: Don't know if this is any use but I'm wondering if somehow they are being set to pending delete and hence are being deleted on restart?

Comment: Just an update for completeness. We were never able to get to the bottom of this but it did only occur when Java was being installed silently?? Why this should make a difference is beyond me, and it wasn't consistent.